# Supermicro X8DAH+-F will not power on

Tags: electrical-power, supermicro

I have a Supermicro X8DAH+-F Rev 2.01 motherboard that will not power on.

I have two Xeon E5645 installed and 6x 8GB 2Rx4 PC3-10600R DIMMs installed in the A and B slots for each channel of each CPU respectively.

[Ram Link](http://www.stalliontek.com/products/parts-upgrades/memory-ram/samsung-8gb-2rx4-pc3-10600r-1333mhz-240-pin-memory-m393b1k70chd-ch9/m393b1k70chd-ch9)

The fans spin briefly then stop when turning on the PSU and the BMC light flashes, but I cannot power on the computer. The BMC does not appear to request a DHCP address. There are no beeps, but I know the beeper works because it beeps if no RAM is installed.

I've attempted a BIOS reset, but am now at a loss.

The CPUs and RAM were taken from a known-working box.

Is this configuration correct? Is there some way to also factory reset the BMC without the computer "powered on"?

Comment: Oh easy... Just call Supermicro support :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4 beeps with this AMIBIOS indicates a problem communicating with the RAM or a clock generation problem on the motherboard.

In my case I identified a damaged pin on cpu socket one that maps to slot 1, bank 1 of the memory controller.

Answer (score 1):

Actually... according to the manual.  (I know... who reads those things?)  ... you need to place the RAM in slots P1-1A, P1-1B, P1-1C, P2-1A, P2-1B, and P2-1C.  Don't just jam them all on slots A & B.

Comment: I thought the manual says that for E5600 series having two banks populated is fine. In fact if you populate all 3 it will be down rated from 1333MHz to 800MHz. Or am I misreading it?

Comment: Also, does the manual say anything about 2Rx4 memory being supported or not?

Comment: From the manual: RDIMM
• 240-pin Reg. DDR3 ECC 1333/1066/800 MHz memory with support of up 
to 288 GB in 18 slots
Note 1. 240-pin Dual Rank (DR) 16 GB Reg. ECC DDR3 1333/1066/800 
MHz memory will support up to 288 GB. Memory speed will be downgraded 
to 800 MHz.
Note 2. 240-pin Quad Rank (QR) 16 GB Reg. ECC DDR3 1066/800 MHz 
memory will support up to 192 GB (with 6 DIMMs max. per CPU). Memory 
speed will be downgraded to 800 MHz.